# Retrieve all values in my loop and format it to json

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to build a page which queries my database and then formats output so another `webservice/page` can access the data.

Ideally I wanted to explore having the data in JSON format, but that is not working. The other problem I have which is more major than the JSON not working is, if I have 3 records in `$reportsResult`, only the last one is displayed.

Anyone with some help please. Oh do I also need to `print_r` for the external webpage to retrieve the data or is there a better way?

```
class Pupil {
    public $FirstName = "";
    public $LastName  = "";
}

foreach($reportsResult->getRecords() as $reportRecord) {
    $Pupil = new Pupil();
    $Pupil->FirstName = $reportRecord->getField('FName');
    $Pupil->LastName = $reportRecord->getField('SName');
}
json_encode($Pupil);
```

OK managed to figure out how how to get all records from the loop, but its still not displaying in json format when I do a print_r - am I missing something?

```
$AllPupils = array();

foreach($reportsResult->getRecords() as $reportRecord)
{

$Pupil = new Pupil();
$Pupil->FamID = $reportRecord->getField('FName');
$Pupil->ChildName = $reportRecord->getField('SName');

array_push($AllPupils, $Pupil);
}

json_encode($AllPupils);
```

Comment: `echo json_encode` not just json_encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably run into issues since `json_encode` wont handle the whole object. for that, you may want to serialize the `$Pupil` object.

Something like below may work for you though. It will assign the values to a returned array, which will allow `json_encode` to execute gracefully:

```
class Pupil {
    public $FirstName = "";
    public $LastName  = "";

    public function getAttr(){
        return array("FirstName" => $this->FirstName, "LastName" => $this->LastName);
    }
}

$json = array();

foreach($reportsResult->getRecords() as $reportRecord) {
    $Pupil = new Pupil();
    $Pupil->FirstName = $reportRecord->getField('FName');
    $Pupil->LastName = $reportRecord->getField('SName');

    $json[] = $Pupil->getAttr();
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, yours worked as well, I'll take Chris's word regarding speed and make your's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime your foreach loop starts again, it will override your `$Pupil` variable.
Try an array instead:

```
$Pupil = array()
$i = 0;
foreach($reportsResult->getRecords() as $reportRecord) {
    $Pupil[$i] = new Pupil();
    $Pupil[$i]->FirstName = $reportRecord->getField('FName');
    $Pupil[$i]->LastName = $reportRecord->getField('SName');
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($Pupil);
```

Edit: **mikemackintosh's** solution should also work and could be a little bit faster (depending on the size of your foreach loop).

To display the results you need to `echo` your data (not only `json_encode`).

Comment: Thank you this works - didnt realise I was suppose to be using echo instead of print_r

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have that class defined, but you know what in your for each have something like

```
foreach ($reportsResult->getRecords() as $key => $record) {
  $data[$key]['firstname'] = $record->getField('Fname');
  $data[$key]['lastname'] = $record->getField('Sname');
}
```

And then you can check the final array using print_r
and while output you can simply do a print json_encode($data) and it will give you a json string of all the items in the data array.

Answer (score 0):

In php (at least), json_encode takes an array as parameter.
Therefore you should add a constructor to your class

```
function __construct($first, $last)
{
    this.$FirstName = $first;
    this.$LastName = $last;
}
```

and one for getting the full name as an array, ready to be jsoned

```
function getNameArray()
{
    $nameArray = array();
    $nameArray['firstName'] = this.$FirstName;
    $nameArray['lastName'] = this.$LastName;

    return $nameArray;
}
```

then in that foreach you build another array with all the pupils

```
$pupils = array();
foreach (bla bla)
{
    $first = $reportRecord->getField('FName');
    $last = $reportRecord->getField('SName');
    $Pupil = new Pupil($first, $last);

    array_push($pupils, $pupil.getNameArray());
}
```

finally, you have everything preped up

```
json_encode($pupils);
```

I'm sure there's other ways to debug your stuff, I use print_r mainly also.